# Require failed for module: csi-filter-test-by gruntfile while trying to run jasmine test with Grunt in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, webstorm

I try to run Jasmine test with grunt in WebStorm. When I run it in console, the test works.

In WebStorm I get this message:

```
[2017-02-27 17:36:28.373] [ERROR] modify-and-run - Error: Require failed for module: csi-filter-test-by-gruntfile. Please check your command line arguments and installed packages are correct.
  at Object.error (C:\xxx\nodejs_testing\node_modules\csi-logger\csi-logger.js:72:24)
    at C:\xxx\nodejs_testing\node_modules\csi-modify-jasmine-test\csi-modify-jasmine-test.js:131:33
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ModifyJasmineTest.getFilters (C:\CPSITA\nodejs_testing\node_modules\csi-modify-jasmine-test\csi-modify-jasmine-test.js:123:22)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\CPSITA\nodejs_testing\node_modules\csi-grunt-modify-and-run\tasks\modify-and-run.js:59:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\nodejs_testing\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:264:15)
    at Object.thisTask.fn (C:\xxx\nodejs_testing\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:82:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\nodejs_testing\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:301:30)
    at Task.runTaskFn (C:\xxx\nodejs_testing\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:251:24)
    at Task.<anonymous> (C:\xxx\nodejs_testing\node_modules\grunt\lib\util\task.js:300:12)
```

The test itself prints hello to console. That's all.

Comment: what command do you use to run it in console? And how do you run it from WebStorm? Please provide a screenshot of your run configuration

Comment: Console from the project folder: grunt --file=specs\non-ui\test.js --system=bmw. When I run it fro mWebStorm, I use grunt configuration, when in parameters I add: --file=specs\non-ui\test.js --system=bmw.

Comment: neither --file nor --system are grunt cli options... please provide your gruntfile.js and screenshot of grunt run configuration